# Tomboy failed to Sync: (500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get Tomboy Sync to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133750/how-do-i-get-tomboy-sync-to-work)

I use Tomboy notes, And I find it very useful to sync the notes through U1, But today when I tried to sync, It showed an error message `Synchronisation failed` or something similar, Without any explanation in details section.
That's the text of `/.config/tomboy/tomboy.log`:

```
07/05/2012 18.10.55 [INFO]: Initializing Mono.Addins
        07/05/2012 18.10.59 [ERROR]: Unparsable last-sync-date element in /home/christian/.config/tomboy/manifest.xml
        07/05/2012 18.11.18 [ERROR]: Caught exception. Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
        07/05/2012 18.11.18 [ERROR]: Stack trace for previous exception:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
        07/05/2012 18.11.18 [ERROR]: Rest of stack trace for above exception:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.MakeWebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parameters, System.String postData)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.WebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.String postData)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.Get(System.String uri, IDictionary`2 queryParameters)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetUser(System.String userUri, IWebConnection connection)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.BeginSyncTransaction()
           at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.SynchronizationThread()
           at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
        07/05/2012 18.11.18 [ERROR]: Synchronization failed with the following exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
        07/05/2012 18.11.28 [ERROR]: Unparsable last-sync-date element in /home/christian/.config/tomboy/manifest.xml
        07/05/2012 18.12.17 [ERROR]: Unparsable last-sync-date element in /home/christian/.config/tomboy/manifest.xml
        07/05/2012 18.12.19 [ERROR]: Caught exception. Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
        07/05/2012 18.12.19 [ERROR]: Stack trace for previous exception:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
        07/05/2012 18.12.19 [ERROR]: Rest of stack trace for above exception:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.MakeWebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parameters, System.String postData)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.WebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.String postData)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.Get(System.String uri, IDictionary`2 queryParameters)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetUser(System.String userUri, IWebConnection connection)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.BeginSyncTransaction()
           at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.SynchronizationThread()
           at System.Threading.Thread.StartInternal()
        07/05/2012 18.12.19 [ERROR]: Synchronization failed with the following exception: The remote server returned an error: (500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
        07/05/2012 18.21.01 [ERROR]: Caught exception. Message: The remote server returned an error: (500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR.
        07/05/2012 18.21.01 [ERROR]: Stack trace for previous exception:   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.CheckFinalStatus (System.Net.WebAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0 
          at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponseData (System.Net.WebConnectionData data) [0x00000] in :0 
        07/05/2012 18.21.01 [ERROR]: Rest of stack trace for above exception:    at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.MakeWebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.Collections.Generic.List`1 parameters, System.String postData)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.WebRequest(RequestMethod method, System.String url, System.String postData)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.OAuth.Get(System.String uri, IDictionary`2 queryParameters)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.Api.UserInfo.GetUser(System.String userUri, IWebConnection connection)
           at Tomboy.WebSync.WebSyncServer.UpdatesAvailableSince(Int32 revision)
           at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.BackgroundSyncChecker()
           at Tomboy.Sync.SyncManager.m__3E(System.Object o)
           at System.Threading.Timer+Scheduler.TimerCB(System.Object o)
And the text of ./config/tomboy/Manifest.xml.

    
    
      0001-01-01T00:00:00.0000000+01:00
      -1
```

How should I fix it?

That's not the first time I have problem with tomboy sync. It never worked with Ubuntu 11.10. I had to upgrade my OS to make it work again.

If the solution is too complicated or impossible, could you suggest me a good alternative? Maybe a tool of Firefox? I tried with Evernote but it doesn't work well with long notes

Comment: I have same issue, on both Ubuntu and Windows, and it has been asked here couple of times. Sometimes it syncs, sometimes it doesn't, and it seems like problem with ubuntuone servers, from debug messages here.

Answer (score 0):

I read around 10 bug reports related to Tomboy failing sync, some pretty dated and still present. It's not just one bug, and your bug (the same I get here) is: `(500) INTERNAL SERVER ERROR`. There are other bugs, some of which have workarounds.

This problem is not a Tomboy bug. It's perhaps not U1 bug, but more like "lost in translation" issue, i.e. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntuone-servers/+bug/554313

What I do now, and see it as sane approach, is to use local folder option for sync. Then sync this local folder with you favorite online storage service (i.e. Dropbox, Ubuntu One, whatever...).
It's basically same thing, but on the safe route

Comment: Thank you. I forgot there's the possibility to use a local folder for sync. That's the best way