# How do I get Tomboy Sync to work? 

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync, tomboy

So I cannot get Tomboy to sync now after the fresh install of 12.04. I have no way of getting the nearly 100 important notes now since 'Notes' has been taken off of 'Ubuntu One' either. When I try to 'Sync' my notes I get an error "Failed to synchronize".

Does anyone know a workaround or what's going on with this. Maybe just a flaw while Ubuntu (Canonical) get everything set for 12.04?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I really need those notes!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is a problem with syncing notes at the moment.

Look here for more information on what is the current status and when the issue will be resolved:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Notes

Comment: Thanks for the link...I will keep an eye on it. Thanks to everyone for helping out!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you still have your old home folder, try looking here:

```
~/.tomboy
~/.local/share/tomboy
```

1. Comment: Set up your home partition on another disk using the
   advanced install options.

   1. Copy all your files to another partition/drive - google this to ensure symlinks..  Install Ubuntu CD/USB and boot to install device.
   2. use gparted to create your drives partitions with boot / on different drive/partition to /home. Make sure that your correct boot
      drive (where grub is to be installed is correct.)
2. Install ubuntu, when you restart, you should have access to your home folders.

   This way even if you re-install your OS, you can set home to this partition and recover all your settings.

Comment: no, unfortunately I completely did a fresh 12.04 install :(

Comment: Next time I will remember to save my "Home" folder (palm2forhead)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Ubuntu One has completely stopped sync support for Tomboy notes, I also had this problem. What I did is just create a Notes folder inside my Dropbox folder, and point my Tomboy notes app to sync there. At least, there's some kind of assurance that my notes are backed-up in the cloud and knows where they are specifically, though I can't make anything out of it unless I have an installed Tomboy app.

Answer (score 0):

The solution by @Duane at http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone/2012/02/05/an-important-note-about-notes/ worked for me.

Thanks

BTW what a blunder to remove the web support and then have this bug in Ubuntu. But at least synch is working for me now